# DynamoDb with ConditionExpression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Consider the following DynamoDb table:

TableName: `foo-bar`
HashKey: `Foo, str`
RangeKey: `Bar, str`
Name: `Baz, str`

Now with the [vogels API](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) I'm trying to insert an item with a HashKey, a new RangeKey, and a Name.

But the Name must not exist for the given HashKey:

So we define the table layout for the vogels API:

```
var foobar = vogels.define("foo-bar", {
    tableName: "foo-bar",
    hashKey: "foo",
    rangeKey: "bar",
    schema: {
        "foo": Joi.string(),
        "bar": Joi.string(),
        "name": Joi.string()
    }
});
```

And then the insertion of the item:

```
var itemToInsert = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar2", name: "TEST" };

var params = {};
params.ConditionExpression = "foo <> :foo AND name <> :name";
params.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
    ":foo": itemToInsert.foo,
    ":name": itemToInsert.name
};

foobar
    .create(itemToInsert, params, function(error, data) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

There is already an item in the table with the following values: `{foo: "foo", bar: "bar", name: "TEST" }`

So I'm expecting the system to give me an error since there is already a match because of the `ConditionExpression`, however the item is inserted without a problem. Is this not possible with DynamoDb?

Notice that it doesn't matter whether I use vogels or directly the aws-sdk, both of them have the same problem, i.e. the item is inserted and the `ConditionExpression` doesn't block the insert.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `vogels`, but what happens if you use a [expression attribute name placeholder](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html#ExpressionAttributeNames) for the attribute **name**? I.e. `"foo <> :foo AND #n <> :name";` and then `params.ExpressionAttributeNames = {"#n": "name"}`. I'm wondering if the error is getting swallowed or something because [name is a reserved word.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html)

Comment: Hey @Mike, thanks for the heads up, however I had to scrub the names for reasons of confidentiality. These are not the actual names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason DynamoDB is inserting your item is because your table is using a compound key of hashkey: foo, rangekey: bar. You are attempting to insert an item with a different key, in this case hashkey: foo, rangekey: bar2. In DynamoDB, when inserting an item the condition expressions are only tested against an existing item matching exactly the same hash and range keys.

You are attempting to add a unique constraint on a non-key attribute, this is not currently possibly with DynamoDB and will require a schema change in order to enforce this constraint.